# Can an EWG behave as an EDG and vice versa?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

Can an Electron Withdrawing Group(EWG)(like NO2, F, Cl, OH, etc.) behave as a Electron Donating group(EDG) in a compound where a carbocation is present in order to stabilise it?

Does the position where it is present or distance from the carbocation affect it's behaviour as an EWG or EDG?

I feel that it should behave as an EDG as carbocation is electron deficient so it has a greater tendency to accept an electron.

Can we say a similar thing that an EDG behaves as an EWG in presence of carbanion as it has excess electrons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. That's why it is called EDG or EWG. It tends to destabilize it more in the absence of other effects like resonance and hyperconjugation.

Comment: I'm afraid this may be an oversimplification; atoms care not for how we categorise them. For example, the fact that halide substituents on a phenyl ring are deactivating/electron-withdrawing yet *ortho/para*-directing suggests there can be simultaneous electron-withdrawing and electron-donating effects in operation, which in this case happens to have a net withdrawing effect. Now what if a bromine atom was linked to 2,4,6-trinitrobenzene? Or a pyrimidine ring? Would it still have a net electron-withdrawing effect into the ring? I have wondered this for a while myself.